# Glossaries conflict with memoir

Tags: memoir, glossaries, warnings

I am having an issue with `glossaries` producing the warning when used with the `memoir` class

```
Package glossaries Warning: overriding `theglossary' environment on input line 4761.
```

A minimum working example is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\printglossary\relax
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Hello World
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

The `\let\printglossary\relax` covers the warning `Package glossaries Warning: Overriding \printglossary on input line 4536`, however this approach will not work for the `theglossary` warning. I realise that this warning is not an error and *could* just be ignored but I would rather prefer to work out a way of suppressing it. Thanks

Comment: `\let\theglossary\relax` might do

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the same style as for `\printglossary`, you can use

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\let\printglossary\relax
\let\theglossary\relax
\let\endtheglossary\relax

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Hello World
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't silence off all warnings by `glossaries`. With `silence` you can override the relevant messages by

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{glossaries}{Overriding \printglossary}
\WarningFilter{glossaries}{Overriding `theglossary'}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Hello World
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks I had tried `\let\theglossary\relax` but had not realised the need for the `\let\endtheglossary\relax` line too

Comment: The second `warningFilter` requires a capital O for the 'overriding' to correctly suppress the warning. I.e. it should read `` \WarningFilter{glossaries}{overriding `theglossary'}``

Comment: @Beavis Indeed it changed! Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Update to [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) version 4.04 and use the `noredefwarn` package option:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[noredefwarn]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

Hello World

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

`glossaries` also has a `nowarn` option that suppresses warnings, but if something unexpected happens it's best to switch the warnings back on.

*Edit:* [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) enables this option by default:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

Hello World

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the package `silence`.

Issue `\WarningsOff*` before loading `glossaries` and `\WarningsOn` after it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningsOff*
\usepackage{glossaries}
\WarningsOn
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Hello World
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

In this way those warnings are gone and all the rest of them in the document are still there.